# is it wa(わ) or は after subject?

Tags: grammar

When I translate something I get the following structure for simple sentence

> subject+"wa"+object+"wo" (google translate uses "o" whereas grammatical sources use wo)+verb (that's the reading in romaji)

> subject+は+object+を+verb

Japanese said not to read Romaji cause that will change the pronunciation of a particle's/character's. But while reading grammar they also used "wa" rather than "ha".

[image]

Should one pronounce that " ha" rather than "wa"?

Comment: I think recommendations not to read romaji are based on the fact that your native language will influence the way you imagine they sound, rather than getting a fresh perspective on the kana. The fact that は is wa or ha in romaji is not the same kind of "changing."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an exception. When は is used as a particle, it's pronounced "wa". But it's still written as は.

As for を, both pronunciations "o" and "wo" exist. I heard them both in Japan, although I'm not sure if it's a regional thing, or a generational thing, and so on.